# Calculate Average Color for Whole Video with ffmeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to calculate the average/median color of a whole video clip (not single frames). Is there a straight forward way to calculate such statistics with ffmpeg or any similar open source tool? I use R for scripting, but a python (or even bash?) solution would also be welcome